# Remove the duplicate blocks from callback function

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm writing a node js program that has to follow the below properties.

1. Check if access token is available in session(`session.user.accessToken`), if that doesn't exist, `console.log` a message.
2. If the access token is available, check if there is `session.attributes.isUserName`, if it is there, `console.log('The values are there');`, if it is not there call the callback method, `console.log('The values are there');`.
3. Basically the code is getting duplicated.

Below is my code.

```
if (!session.user.accessToken) {
       console.log('Token is not available');
    } else {
        if (!session.attributes.isUserName) {
         getUserDetailsFromToken(session, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
               //print the user's data.
                console.log("UserName is " + session.attributes.userName);
            }
        });
        } else{
             //print the user's data.
             console.log("UserName is " + session.attributes.userName);
        }

        }
    }
```

Here `session.attributes.userName` that we are printing is same, just that the call back `getUserDetailsFromToken` checks and sets a variable. Is there a way that I can get the `console.log("UserName is " + session.attributes.userName);` out of code and use it seperately? this is a sample code that I've provided, I've 126 lines of code in my application, those have to be duplicated, once inside callback (`if` condition), and another outside callback (`else` condition).

Please let me know how can I optimize this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used to do

```
var feedback = () => {
    //print the user's data.
    console.log("UserName is " + session.attributes.userName);
}

if (!session.user.accessToken) {
   console.log('Token is not available');

} else {
    if (!session.attributes.isUserName) {
        getUserDetailsFromToken(session, function (err) {
            if (!err) feedback();
        });

    } else {
        feedback();
    }
}
```

And just a suggestion, with some simple refactor on code it would looks cleaner, less if-else nested statements:

```
var feedback = () => {
    //print the user's data.
    console.log("UserName is " + session.attributes.userName);
}

do {
    if (!session.user.accessToken) {
        console.log('Token is not available');
        break;
    }

    if (session.attributes.isUserName) {
        feedback();
        break;
    }

    getUserDetailsFromToken(session, function (err) {
        if (!err) feedback();
    });

} while(0);
```